# How can I combine COUNT(*) for two different ActiveRecord relations into a single SQL query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

With two different ActiveRecord relation objects, is there a way to issue one SQL query to compare the counts of the relations?

eg. say I have two ActiveRecord::Relation objects like this:

```rb
posts = Post.where().where().some_scope
users = User.where().some_other_scope.where().joins(:something)
```

To compare the counts of each relation, I'd have to issue two SQL queries.

```
posts.count == users.count
# => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE... ;
# => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users INNER JOIN ... WHERE... ;
```

I want to be able to issue just one query. Something like:

```
Post.select("COUNT(first) == COUNT(second) as are_equal"), posts, users).are_equal
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to combine two counts over two different tables into one query, unless you use a `UNION`. Which will run the two separate queries and merge the results. This will take about the same time as running the two queries separately, except you only go to the db-server once (1 query), but you loose readability. So imho I really wonder if that is worth it.

E.g. in the one case you can write

```
 if posts.count == users.count
```

In the other case one would write:

```
 count_sql = <<-SQL 
    select "Posts" as count_type, count(*) from posts where ... 
    union 
    select "Users" as count_type, count(*) from users where ...
 SQL 

 result = Post.connection.execute(count_sql) 
 if result[0]["count"] == result[1]["count"]
```

You will have to decide if the performance improvement ways up to the loss of readability.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. Probably not worth it just to have one less roundtrip to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with ActiveRecord query methods, but the underlying Arel query builder (which ActiveRecord uses internally) can achieve this, it just looks a bit less elegant:

```
posts = Post.where().where().some_scope
users = User.where().some_other_scope.where().joins(:something)

posts_table = Post.arel_table
users_table = User.arel_table

posts_count = Arel::Nodes::Count.new([posts_table[:id]]).as('count')
users_count = Arel::Nodes::Count.new([users_table[:id]]).as('count')

union = posts.select(posts_count).arel.union(users.select(users_count).arel)

post_count, user_count = Post.from(posts_table.create_table_alias(union, :posts)).map(&:count)
```

Although it may not actually be beneficial in this case (as discussed in other answers), it's worth being aware of Arel because there are times where it is useful - I always try to avoid raw SQL in my Rails applications and Arel makes that possible.

An excellent introduction can be found here: https://danshultz.github.io/talks/mastering_activerecord_arel/#/

Answer (score 0):

You can always write your own SQL query.

Let's say you have two models, AdminUser and Company. One way of doing what you want would be the following:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) as nb from admin_users UNION SELECT COUNT(*) as nb from companies;").to_a
```

You'll end up with an array of two hashes, each containing the number of records of each database table.